# Recharts customized bar chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, recharts

I use Recharts bar chart https://recharts.org/en-US/.

I need to make a customized one.

And I already made the upper one (see picture).

How can I customize the min and max and the bar to become like the bottom (see picture)?

Feel like I will need to change the data itself?

data:
{
name: "data1",
total: 50
},
{
name: "data2",
total: 6900
},
{
name: "data3",
total: 7000
}

[image]

Comment: Have you figured out it yet? I have the same problem

Comment: @M.Tae hey I haven't in the end. cuz it actually doesn't make any sense.